# Battlepass level 1000 reward from steam-market

Tags: steam, dota-2

Level 1000 in Battlepass 2017 is a 1:5 replica of Aegis. After you become level 1000 you will get [an item](https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/570/The%20International%202017%20-%20Battle%20Level%201000) which is similar to Aegis and is tradeable on the market.

Is this item enough to get a replica from Valve, or do I need to make my own Battlepass level 1000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as I read You have to get 1000 battlepass level to be able to get the real replica.

"All Battle Pass owners who reach Battle Level 1000 are invited to receive The International 2016 Collector’s Aegis, an exclusive 1/5th-scale, bronze-plated alloy replica of the famed champion’s prize."

Comment: You are right, but at level 1000 you get to your steam/dota2 inventory item which represents your claim on real aegis, and this item is tradeable, so if you sell it who will have rights to real aegis, you as battlepass owner or buyer from market which owns this item?

Comment: Replica will be given to the owner of battlepass who has reached 1 000 levels. This in-game replica is set until the end of the battlepass and then it will dissapear.